# REST answer can't be parsed - how to make it process correctly

Tags: java, json, angular, parsing, endpoint

After sending a REST POST request from an Angular frontend to a Java backend, the backend recieves the request and computes the answer. However, in the frontend, the request does not show up in the logs, instead a parsing error is given.

There is a Rest-Call from an Angular endpoint, which is:

```
getUserID<NonSimpleObject>(nonSimpleObject: NonSimpleObject): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.post<string>(this.API_URL + '/userId', nonSimpleObject);
}
```

it is recieved in the Java Endpoint which is:

```
@POST
@Path("/userId")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String userId(NonSimpleObject nonSimpleObject) {
    LOG.info("The searched UserId is: " + controller.getUserId(nonSimpleObject);
    return controller.getUserId(nonSimpleObject);
}
```

In the backend, the log shows that the request arrives and the string is computed correctly. The string is an alphanumeric combination, no special characters. In the frontend, the chrome log shows no trace of the request, but gives the error

```
ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at JsonParser.parse (json-parser.service.ts:64:21)
    at CustomJsonParserHttpInterceptor.parseJsonResponse (custom-json-parser-h…nterceptor.ts:47:50)
    at custom-json-parser-h…nterceptor.ts:42:64
    at map.js:7:37
    at OperatorSubscriber._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:13:21)
    at OperatorSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:31:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.mjs:1840:30)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:26341:33)
```

I would expect to recieve the String in an ok Response from the backend. Any clues on how to make the request process properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing the string as generic type is not enough for Angular to treat it as string. Angular still tries to parse json and fails here. Please also set the responseType option.

```
return this.http.post(this.API_URL + '/userId', nonSimpleObject, { responseType: 'text' });
```

Besides that your service is not quiet correct. It produces a string, but you say it produces a json. Please also change the Produces MediaType:

```
 @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
```

Comment: That gives the error in the IDE:
Type 'Observable<ArrayBuffer>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<string>'.
Changing the type to ArrayBuffer gives:
No overload matches this call.
However setting { responsetype: 'text' as 'json' } seems to work. If you adress this I will mark the question as answered by your post

Comment: ArrayBuffer would be 'arraybuffer' (see https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest). There is nothing wrong with my answer, it is the correct way handling a string. I guess that happens due to your Produces annotation, I changed my answer asking for a change here too.

Comment: Probably the version of POST that accepts responseType:'text' is not generic? That seems to be a  thing with GET (see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18672#issuecomment-455435341) What seems to work is return this.http.post(this.API_URL + '/gutachterverwaltung/vpnUserId', vpnUserIdVO, { responseType: 'text' }); without the <string>. However for some reason my backend behaves strangely when i use it, so i can't verify with certainty

Answer (score 0):

I needed another solution as the non-generic version of the endpoint caused problems for me. If someone else is also looking for an alternative solution:

The response of

```
getUserID<NonSimpleObject>(nonSimpleObject: NonSimpleObject): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.post<string>(this.API_URL + '/userId', nonSimpleObject);
}
```

will be a string without ", which, as MoxxiManagarm stated, will not be parsed correctly. However, adding the " before and after the string-to-be-returned on the backend-side will make it parse correctly in the frontend.

So the Java endpoint will be:

```
@POST
@Path("/userId")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String userId(NonSimpleObject nonSimpleObject) {
    return '"' + controller.getUserId(nonSimpleObject) + '"';
}
```